# phpMyAdmin login by http

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, authentication, phpmyadmin

I want to login by http to phpMyadmin. Now I tried this:
`localhost/phpmyadmin/?pma_user=root&pma_password=blaat&server=1`. But I want to 'hide' the password. Is there a way to encrypt the password, so you can't see it in the front end?

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Since Version 4.9.0 the above example won't work either - see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=URL#which-parameters-can-i-use-in-the-url-that-starts-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

No, not really without hacking on phpMyAdmin a LOT. Basically to "encrypt" the password, you'd need a lot of javascript, which would need to be added and then phpMyAdmin would need to be told not to hash the password itself.

Even if you "encrypt" or "hide" the only the password, you're not safe. Using POST instead of GET would make it look hidden, but any script kiddie could still sniff a POST field. And making it encrypted would still make you just as vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack (they could intercept the hashed password and just re-submit it themself as though it were just a regular old password, and it would still work).

The only "encryption" you'll get in the truest sense is by using HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: This isn't logging in via HTTP Auth - that would be something like `http://root:blaat@localhost/phpmyadmin?server=1`.

I know that PHPMyAdmin has support for specifying the username and password credentials in the configuration file so that the user doesn't need to seem them at all.

Might this be a better way to achieve your goal?

Comment: Yes, would be interesting. But how would PMA now that when I send, for example 'test' in the URL, it needs to login with 'user'/'blaat' and when I send 'test2', it needs to login with 'user2'/'pass2'?

Comment: You can have multiple server configurations in the configuration file.  I'm afraid I don't have specifics, I just know it exists!  There's more information in the documentation: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#cfg_Servers

Answer (score -2):

Use HTTP POST instead of GET in your form.  Or if you're just building a link currently, you'll need to [whip up a quick HTML form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) to handle this.  If you have SSL available, use HTTPS.

Comment: It's not encrypted, it's just not shown in the URL. Use HTTPS to encrypt the password.

Comment: @Konerak - **both** are security concerns.  Even if you use HTTPS, someone can easily look over your shoulder and see a link with the password exposed.

Comment: @Konerak HTTPS would still show up in the logs too?  Bad ju-ju.  I just think the OP is going about this the wrong way, tbh.